# i can't seem to get my hover effects to work on button. have tried many tips

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, frontend

i am new and this is my first real assignment. i was able to get it right in other challenges but this one is a bit more complex and for some reason i just don't see where i'm going wrong. i have googled many options and none have really helped. i may have been staring at this for to long. but any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>3 day Forecast</title>
    <style>
      h1 {
        color: #1a64d6;
        font-size: 34px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 34px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        line-height: 48px;
      }
      h3 {
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
      }
      ul {
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 20px;
        display: block;
      }
      p {
        opacity: 0.7;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      li {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
      }
      button {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #1a64d6;
        background-color: #1a64d6;
        display: block;
        margin: 20px auto;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 16px 24px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
      }
      footer {
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 0.7;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
      button:hover {
        color: white;
        background: #1a64d6;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      ⛅
      <br />
      Currently 21° in Tokyo
    </h1>

    <h2>
      13° /
      <strong> 23° </strong>
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3> Tomorrow</h3>
        <p>10° / <strong> 22°</strong></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>⛅ Saturday</h3>
        <p>15° / <strong> 17°</strong></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>☀ Sunday</h3>
        <p>25° / <strong> 28°</strong></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button>Change City</button>
    <footer>Coded by: Tiffany Asbell</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you don't see the hover effect working because in your button:hover nothing is different

Comment: Everything is ok in your code. You can't see the changes because you didn't change anything in the button hover. Change background color to different color in hover state. Then you will see the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change any of the values in your button:hover selector. For example change the color from white to black and you should see a difference when you hover.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. i was focusing to much on my actual code structure i totally blocked that out. i'm new at this so any tips are welcome. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The button and button:hover has the same property value. Change color or background color property value in button:hover you can see the difference.

For example,

```
button{
    color:white;
    background-color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: i feel like a dingus lol! thanks so much for pointing that out. i was focusing so hard on the code i didn't even think about the colors.